# How to get the parent li class in jsTree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jstree

How do I get the parent li class in jsTree plugin? Whenever I try to traverse the Javascript tree, I can get to the parent node, but I end up with an object and can never get it to output the parent class as a string, so I can do a simple conditional check against it.

Here's what I want to do:

```
  // JS Tree Event handler for when a node is clicked
  $("#dutchData").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    // get the parent node class, and then use it in a conditional statement
    var parentNodeClass = data.node.parent.attr('class'); // this is wrong, just to demonstrate
    if(parentNodeClass != 'x'){
      // do something
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `parent` property is not the element but a string id of the element. You can get the parent with jQuery and then get class like so:

`$('#'+data.node.parent).attr('class');`

Check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ffzg71v1/)

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay. I see it working in your Fiddle, but for some reason the same thing does not work in my code. If anyone else finds this post, I hope it works for them, as it seems like it should. I've since taken another path to avoid this issue altogether. Thanks again.